# when multiple CheckBoxes within a repeater control is checked the .aspx page will refresh in chrome browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net, aspx, firefox, chrome

I am using a repeater control in a web part. The repeater control contains a checkbox. when I select more than one checks in the repeater checkboxes the page is getting refreshed. This happens only in chrome and firefox browsers.

Comment: Do you have `AutoPostBack=True` for the checkbox?

Comment: yes. @ArsalanAdamKhatri

Comment: Do you have SelectedIndexChanged or any other event implemented at the backend? If not, remove `AutoPostBack=True` and you should be fine

Comment: I am using OnCheckedChanged event inside the repeater.
 <asp:CheckBox ID="DependentCheckBox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="DependentCheckBox_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />

Answer (score 0):

For Non-IE browser turn of the Cache mechanism which can cause this type of issues with AjaxCalls

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Request.Browser.MSDomVersion.Major == 0) // Non IE Browser?
   {
       Response.Cache.SetNoStore(); // No client side cashing for non IE browsers
   }
}
```